# routing problems in razor pages

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, visual-studio, asp.net-core-3.1

This one has been driving me nuts for a couple of weeks now, so if anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful.

I'm developing a relatively simple CRUD application using .net core and Razor Pages.

I've used Visual Studio 2019 community to start a new application and I've asked for the standard CRUD option.  With a bit of tweaking and a database creation, the application works fine.  Here's the standard .net core table display for a table called "categories"

[image]

However, I wanted a rather prettier table, so I am trying to use an ajax call from some JavaScript.

On the page I have

```html
    <div class="col-12 border p-3">

        <table id="DT_load" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>In Use?</th>


                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
@section Scripts
{

    <script src="~/js/categoryList.js"></script>

}
```

This points to this Javascript

```js
var dataTable;


$(document).ready(function () {
    loadDataTable();
    alert($('#DT_load').html())
    });

    function loadDataTable() {

    dataTable = $('#DT_load').dataTable
         ({
            "ajax":
            {
                "url": "/controllers/categories",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns":
                [
                  { "data": "id", "width": "50%" },
                  { "data": "category", "width": "50%" },
                  { "data": "inUse", "width": "50%" },
                ],
            "language":
                {
                "emptyTable": "no data found"
            },
            "width": "100%"
        });
}
```

Which should..........   Then access this controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Investments10.Models;

namespace Investments10
{
[Route("api/Category")]
//[Route("api/CategoryController")]
[ApiController]
public class CategoriesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly aspnetInvestments1053bc9b9d9d6a45d484292a2761773502Context _context;

    public CategoriesController(aspnetInvestments1053bc9b9d9d6a45d484292a2761773502Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/Categories
    [HttpGet]
    public async  Task<ActionResult> GetAllCategory()

    {

        return new JsonResult (new { data = await _context.Category.ToListAsync() });
    }

    // GET: api/Categories/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Category>> GetCategory(int id)
    {
        var category = await _context.Category.FindAsync(id);

        if (category == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return category;
    }
```

However, it never gets to the controller.  I've stuck a few break points into the controller, and it's not getting there.  I suspect the problem is in the URL that I have specified for the Ajax call, but I've tried a whole bunch of variants, and none of them seem to get the call accessing the controller.

The file structure is below.

[image]

What's particularly irritating is that I know that this technique works, because I have an almost identical example from someone else's project that works fine.

Any help would be very gratefully received.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add your action route attributes like these:

```
.........

    [Route("~/api/Category/GetAllCategory")]
    public async  Task<ActionResult> GetAllCategory()

  ............

   [Route("~/api/Category/GetCategory/{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Category>> GetCategory(int id)
  
.......
```

And for the future, better not use GET , POST etc  in the actions. Computer knows better what to use for the request.

Comment: Thanks Sergey.  Much appreciated.  I'll try that out.

Answer (score 0):

Ah hah!   I have found the issue.  In order to make use of routing in controllers, I needed to add the line

```
            endpoints.MapControllers();
```

into my startup.cs file